# Can anyone tell me if there were any planned follow-ups to The Prisoner? If so, what were they?

Tags: tv, the-prisoner

Patrick McGoohan's The Prisoner is one of the great television shows. Like Firefly, it was very short (17 episodes).  It was brought to a somewhat hasty conclusion.

Does anyone know if there were any episodes, movies or stories on any other media planned as follow-ups?  If there were, is any of it available for access?

Comment: It was neither short nor brought to an unexpected conclusion. In fact, quite the contrary. Typical UK series last *8* episodes. The Prisoner was originally intended to have just seven, but the channel convinced McGoohan to write more to allow it to be sold overseas. That's why some of the episodes are on the thin side.

Comment: For some reason, my personal head-canon is that the Village eventually gets run down and becomes Dibley.

Comment: @rws If you're still interested in this question, the BBC is currently (as of 20 March 2019) airing their 2016 radio series. https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/m0001f39

Comment: Firefly is only 14 episodes.

Comment: https://youtu.be/CoG6SiBvpkA interview of Alexis Kanner.  Specifically sequel mentioned at 2:30 mark of this interview.   I think I recall in other places also claims that Alexis Kanner the young man No. 48 in Fall Out was going to be a McGoohan replacement in a sequel series.  Hopefully this wasn't a joke as the Olympics comment here seems a little absurd whereas when I first saw this interview I wouldn't question it.

Answer (score 9):

The Prisoner has had a few adaptations and sequels, mostly in other media (not counting the recent [TV remake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner_%282009_miniseries%29)).

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner_in_other_media) is a good resource listing some of the newer works.

I read [Shattered Visage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shattered_Visage) when it came out, and was not too disappointed. While nothing has (in my opinion) captured the original appeal and oddness, this was a nice stopgap. I especially liked seeing the Penny-farthing on the cover of each issue.

[image]

Comment: I liked Shattered Visage, I thought it was interesting and thought provoking. Dean Motter did a good job connecting to the series while still trying something original.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Shattered Visage is completely new to me - I'll track it down ASAP.  And the Wikipedia link is pretty interesting.  Much appreciated!